# Selecting rows of data table where column "machine" matches and "weekly sales" > "weekly sales" in different data table

Tags: r

I have two data tables in R.
Table 1: Weekly Sales, where I have the average sales of a certain product in a machine per week

| Machine | Product | Week | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Water | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | Cake | 2 | 6 |

Table 2: Average Weekly Sales, where I have the average weekly sales over the entire year of a prodcu in a machine

| Machine | Product | Avg. Weekly Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Water | 2.4 |
| 2 | Cake | 3.8 |

I would now like to retrieve all the rows in Table 1(Weekly Sales) where a certain product in a specific machine was sold more often than on average from Table 2 (Average Weekly Sales)

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge `table1` and `table2` and keep rows where `Sales > Avg.Weekly.Sales`.

Using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

table1 %>%
  inner_join(table2, by = c('Machine', 'Product')) %>%
  filter(Sales > Avg.Weekly.Sales)
```

Base R :

```
subset(merge(table1, table2, by = c('Machine', 'Product')), Sales > Avg.Weekly.Sales)
```